# Is there any way to tell Team City to treat empty files result as noop and not raise an error?

Tags: teamcity

I have a step in a build template where I set the pattern for searching files. For some projects these files do not exist; TeamCity believes it to be a error:

> Target files not found for pattern "**/Release/*.nupkg"

I would like to give TC a hint that it is ok, and the step may be simple omitted. Is it possible?

P.S. Thought here I show the pattern for NuGet packages, but I have similar issues with other steps.

Answer (score 3):

If it's ok in some of the projects, then you can mute this problem there and it won't fail the build anymore.

Comment: Could you tell where exactly I can make TC ignore this particular error?

Comment: Do you see a build problem related to this error on build results page? If so, there is a popup associated with it where you can mute it.